# Eclipse Windows 10 permission denied on http requests

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, permissions

An existing instance of Eclipse has suddenly developed issues when attempting to make connections over HTTP.

- I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers Version 4.5.2...
- I am running Eclipse in as an Administrator.
- I am able to make service to service calls locally without issue.

Upon attempting to communicate over HTTP I get the following error :

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
at com.cardinalcommerce.util.io.TimedHttpUrlConnection$URLStreamReader.run(TimedHttpUrlConnection.java:264)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've verified that URL in question does exist and is accessible through my browser.

Other fun facts : the Eclipse installer (by Oomph!) experiences the same error when it attempts to install Eclipse.  If I install a new instance of Eclipse without the installer the Eclipse market place experiences the same error - but my existing instance does not experience any problems communicating with the marketplace.

Comment: DId you upgrade Java.  Does the Windows Firewall know that Java is allowed to make network connections?

Comment: I have not recently upgraded java - I'm using 1.8.  At some point in the process of trying to work through this the firewall was turned off and the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your browser has a proxy configured. You'll need to configure the same in the [eclipse proxy settings](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/)

Comment: There is no proxy configured.